# Navigation Property does not reflect

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

The navigation property that i have doesnt reflect on my odata results but I am assigning values on that property. Here's the code.

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
            {
                var mainEntity = new EdmEntityObject(entityType);
                mainEntity.TrySetPropertyValue("Id", "AllKey" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity.TrySetPropertyValue("UserName", "AccountId" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity.TrySetPropertyValue("EmailAddress", "EmailAddress@EmailAddress.com" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity.TrySetPropertyValue("FirstName", "FirstName" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity.TrySetPropertyValue("LastName", "LastName" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity.TrySetPropertyValue("Custom", "Custom" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity.TrySetPropertyValue("[BasicProperty]Id", "[BasicProperty]Id" + x.ToString());

                IEdmEntityTypeReference categoryType = entityType.FindNavigationProperty("UserLogin").Type.AsEntity();

                var mainEntity2 = new EdmEntityObject(categoryType);
                mainEntity2.TrySetPropertyValue("Id", "AllKey" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity2.TrySetPropertyValue("UserName", "AccountId" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity2.TrySetPropertyValue("EmailAddress", "EmailAddress@EmailAddress.com" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity2.TrySetPropertyValue("FirstName", "FirstName" + x.ToString());
                mainEntity2.TrySetPropertyValue("LastName", "LastName" + x.ToString());

                mainEntity.TrySetPropertyValue("UserLogin", mainEntity2);                    

                collectionProduct.Add(mainEntity);
            }
```

Here's the result.

```
{

"@odata.context": "http://localhost/WebApi/enwisen/User_Entity/$metadata#User_Entity",
"value": [
    {
        "UserName": "AccountId1",
        "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress@EmailAddress.com1",
        "Id": "AllKey1",
        "FirstName": "FirstName1",
        "LastName": "LastName1",
        "Custom": "Custom1"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "AccountId2",
        "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress@EmailAddress.com2",
        "Id": "AllKey2",
        "FirstName": "FirstName2",
        "LastName": "LastName2",
        "Custom": "Custom2"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "AccountId3",
        "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress@EmailAddress.com3",
        "Id": "AllKey3",
        "FirstName": "FirstName3",
        "LastName": "LastName3",
        "Custom": "Custom3"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "AccountId4",
        "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress@EmailAddress.com4",
        "Id": "AllKey4",
        "FirstName": "FirstName4",
        "LastName": "LastName4",
        "Custom": "Custom4"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "AccountId5",
        "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress@EmailAddress.com5",
        "Id": "AllKey5",
        "FirstName": "FirstName5",
        "LastName": "LastName5",
        "Custom": "Custom5"
    }
]

}
```

Here's the metadata

```
<EntityType Name="User">
<Key>
   <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="UserName" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="EmailAddress" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="LastName" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Custom" Type="Edm.String"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="GroupLookup" Type="Collection(Enwisen.GroupLookup)"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="UserLogin" Type="Enwisen.UserLogin" Nullable="false/>
</EntityType>
```

Notice that I have a navigation property but it doesnt reflect on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you are writing your GET request as

```
http://localhost/WebApi/enwisen/User_Entity/User_Entity
```

You need to write your query as follows:

```
http://localhost/WebApi/enwisen/User_Entity/User_Entity?$expand=UserLogin
```

Thus the navigation property will be shown in the response payload.

OData protocol reference: [11.2.4.2 System Query Option $expand](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793688).

Comment: Back when I'm using wcf data services odata the navigation properties appear even if i didnt use expand. It have a link associated with it. I dont know if web api have different behaviour.

Comment: The default payload type returned by WCF Data Services is Atom. Association links and navigation links of navigation properties are by default included in Atom payloads. I think the payload that your Web API service returns is probably JSON payload. For V3 OData services, to include navigation links in the JSON payload, you can request the payload as http://localhost/WebApi/enwisen/User_Entity/User_Entity?$format=application/json;odata=verbose. For V4 services, you should request http://localhost/WebApi/enwisen/User_Entity/User_Entity?$format=application/json;odata.metadata=full.

Comment: Great! I can see now the navigation properties. Thanks @Yi Ding

Comment: It works if i'm returning a single result like IEdmEntityObject but when I'm returning collections it throws an error "**The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata.metadata=full; charset=utf-8'.**". any idea on what is the problem here?

Comment: You can perhaps refer to this question for answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154475/net-webapi-odata-actions-that-return-an-queryable